# Remove all documnets in numerous collections where a document contains a substring using regex or Let

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query, sql-like

Afternoon All,

I need to remove all old documents from past end of months from many collections in a single MongoDB. Previously I was manually updating each collection:

```
db.df_FI.deleteMany({ "key" : /2019-05-01_2019-05-30_Reported/}) 
db.df_Final_FI.deleteMany({ "key" : /2019-05-01_2019-05-30_Reported/}) 
db.df_Manual_Booked_FI.deleteMany({ "key" : /2019-05-01_2019-05 30_Reported/}) 
db.df_Manual_Booked_Final_FI.deleteMany({ "key" : /2019-05-01_2019-05-30_Reported/})
```

I'd like to paramatise this. I tried regex and let but to no avail. Updating one collection example

```
db.df_FI.deleteMany(
                         { 
                             key :         "$regex" : key_sub_string
                         }
                     )

db.df_FI.remove(    
                    { $expr: { $in: [ "$key", "$$key_sub_string" ] } },
                    { let : { key_sub_string: "2021-08-01_2021-08-11_Reported" } }
               )
```

Either fail to update.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

You can making the string surely
However, try doing it like this

```
modelName.deleteMany({ yourColumnNameInModel: { $gte: key_sub_string } }).then(function(){
     // Success
}).catch(function(error){
    // Not Success    });
```

**Also,** Why are you adding reported at the end of your variable?

Comment: There are other strings beside _Reported. Whats the command to delete the "Success" documents?

Comment: This deleted 2 million records. Looks like the gte does not work.